# Garages known to fraudulently upsale

Tags: data-request

I am looking for a dataset containing a list of garage known to fraudulently upsale (=inducing the customer to purchase unnecessary items, upgrades, repairs or other add-ons in an attempt to make a more profitable sale. [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-avpx8UTakI), [mirror](http://www.cbc.ca/1.2418675)).

Ideally, the dataset should contain information pertaining to the detection of the fraudulent upsales (e.g., fraudulent upsale detected by CBC Marketplace on  2016-06-16).

---

I am mostly interested in the following locations:

- California, United States
- Massachusetts, United States
- Paris, France
- Seoul, South Korea